# Is creating a new user in Amazon Cognito and sharing his credentials publicly a good practice?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-cognito

I have a backend app that provides measurement data through the use of REST API.

Now, I'm creating a frontend app that can visualize and query that data depending on parameters such as `city`, `fromDateTime`, `tillDateTime`, `sponsorId` etc.

I'd like to assign attributes to specific users that would describe how visualization should look like and what exactly they can query from my REST API. For example, a specific sponsor of measurement devices can only see data from the devices they bought.

However, I'd like them to be able to make their data public. How to do that?

I thought, in that kind of situation, I could make a new user with appropriate attributes and make its credentials public. Then, create a URL with something like `/user/{username}/data/` in the path. The `username` could be randomly generated and the password could be the same to all public users and could be hardcoded into the frontend app.

What do you think about this approach? Is it a good idea? Is it secure? Maybe there's another better way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like part of your application is only available to authenticated users and part of it to unauthenticated (public) users.

You are already using Cognito for the authenticated users. Sounds like you've done the hard part of locking that data down to the right users. The question is, why would you involve Cognito at all for your unauthenticated users? Sounds like the right answer would be to put the public data in a location that is publicly accessible in your application.

EDIT: I would not use Cognito to store application data. Whilst your data may relate to a user, it doesn't sound like authentication and authorisation data. More importantly, if you are accessing this data frequently for application purposes, Cognito is not scalable in the same way as something like DynamoDB. If you are still in design phase, I think perhaps you should look at putting this data into a database instead of Cognito.

Comment: This is because: 1. I want to have many modifiable templates (I don't want to hardcode how my visualization looks like in my frontend app - I'd like to store that information somewhere else - ideally in Cognito). 2. Private content can be made public at any time. I don't want to store information about what is public and what is not in my backend app. This way that app stays fully stateless. Perhaps I could add a database which would store information about what is public and what is not but how advantageous would that be in comparison to using Cognito?

Comment: So, generally, my frontend app would read the user's claim - read my custom attributes describing what the user can query - then, depending on that a proper visualization would be presented. If a user accesses public URL, the frontend app would read `username` from URL path, use some default password and read my custom attributes assigned to that public user generating appropriate visualization using the same logic. Please say if something is unclear to you.